# Why are meta tags moved into body?

Tags: html, unicode, encoding

I declared my `<meta>` tags inside `<head>` but when the browser is parsing they get moved inside the `<body>`. The result was the same when I disabled JavaScript. Here is the screenshot illustrating the problem: [screenshot from browser](http://img.uz/s?i315g2d).

Comment: You wrote "I declared my meta tags inside". But not clear where? Can you post the part where you have added this meta tag?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, too. What it was was I tried to use `<meta>` tags like this: `<meta name="author">Me</meta>` but that's not right. You have to go through and change them all to this: `<meta name="author" content="Me">`.

Comment: You might also want to put `/>` at the end of the tag instead of just `>` like so: `<meta name="author" content="Me" />`

Answer (score 1):

Please open the developer tool, navigate to the network tab, click the HTML doc request, you'll found the red dot on the doc's first line, hover your pointer over it, you'll see the error char. the reason is that your HTML file encoding error, just switch it to UTF-8, not UTF-8 with BOM.
[error doc sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J45HL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing has occurred to me, it seems to be some kind of encoding problem.
In my case I managed to fix the problem by opening all of my html files and resaving them with UTF-8 (without BOM) encoding (I did that with Sublime Text editor, but I guess you can do that with anything else, like Notepad++).